# kafka-connect JDBC PostgreSQL Sink Connector explicitly define the PostgrSQL schema (namespace)

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect

I am using the JDBC sink connector to write data to postgresql.

The connector works fine, but it seems the connector can only write data to the default postgresql schema called `public`

This is the common JDBC URL format for postgresql.

`jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port5432>/<database>`

Is it possible to explicitly define the schema name, to which I need the postgresql sink connector to write?

**UPDATE**:

Thanks, @Laurenz Albe for the hint. I can define `search_path` in the jdbc connection URL like either of these:

`jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>?options=-c%20search_path=myschema,public`

`jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>?currentSchema=myschema`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `options` connection parameter to set the `search_path`:

```
jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port5432>/<database>?options=-c%20search_path=myschema,public
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, your recommendation works perfectly, and this is indeed a search path question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"table.name.format: schema.${topic}"`. It will be written to the given schema only.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).